# Butterknife Required view with ID for field was not found in every fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, butterknife

When I try to bind my views with Butterknife I get this `IllegalStateException` after every time I call `ButterKnife.bind(this, fragmentView!!)` method.

For example:

```
//...BindView section
@BindView(R.id.logoutButton)
lateinit var logoutButton: View

@BindView(R.id.closeSession)
lateinit var closeSessionButton: View

@BindView(R.id.settings)
lateinit var settingsButton: View
```

And I get this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>       Required view login with ID 2131362018 for field logoutButton was not found. 
>       If this view is optional add @Nullable (fields) or @Optional (methods) annotation.

The point is that I DIDN'T BIND the 'login' view as the exception says.
I bounded 'logutButton'.
I did have 'login' view, but in the other fragment which has no connection to fragment where the exception appears.

And this happening in every fragment, activity, or adapter or something else which needs binding views with butterknife.
 And every time Butterknife tries to bind, an absolutely random view for the field that comes first in declaration order (only first `@BindView` annotation affected, the next annotation are fine)

I'm using `@Nullable` annotation and it's helping perfectly (even after I deleted `@Nullable` annotation - fragment works fine). But I have lots of fragments and activities, so I can't check all of them and add the `@Nullable` annotation.

**How I can find the source of this problem so that it never happens again?**

Comment: You do not need butterknife when using kotlin.. kotlin android extensions provide direct access to layout view objects!

Comment: try after clean and build

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how i solved this:

> **Build -> Clean Project**

And everything fine!

Answer (score 1):

Using Butterknife in kotlin project is pointless. Kotlin already provides direct and easy access to layout and its view. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

You should stop using butterknife and remove thislibrary from gradle.

Comment: The kotlin.syntethic plugin is not recommended by Google. [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/efdvpkg?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Answer (score 0):

Your layout xml file didn't have the widget with id 'R.id.logoutButton', you can quote the id in your Activity maybe because you set that id in other xml layout files, not the one you were using in current activity.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding this annotation `@Nullable` or `@Optional`. I have taken reference from https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/343

```
@Nullable
@BindView(R.id.tvTitle)
```